# Output categories from a CatGroup, as 'group/list' of category related entries EEv2.9

Tags: categories, low-reorder

New to EE overall but trying to output 'lists' of category specific entries within a specific category group. Essentially the logic I think I need is:
'for *unique* each category in categoryGroup output entries with associated category as a group/list of entries'

Low-reorder plugin sets can be created and are used elsewhere but this doesnt seem to get me where I want to go with regards to the output.

Any advice/code snippets would surely be appreciated.

[Category Hierarchy]
-Category Group
  - Cat 1
  - Cat 2

[Ideal Output]
- Cat 1 Name
   - entry A
   - entry B
- Cat 2 Name
   - entry A
   - entry C

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="xxx" show="x|y|z" style="linear"}
   <h1>{category_name}</h1>
   <ul>
   {exp:channel:entries channel="xxx" category="{category_id}" dynamic="no"}
      <li>{title}</li>
   {/exp:channel:entries}
   </ul>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Clearly you will need to add your own information - vis replace "xxx" with your channel name - and if you only want a limited number of categories put the category numbers you want in the 'show' parameter in place of x, y, z etc.

HTH